# Extract number from specific string pattern in string

Tags: regex, bash

I am iterating through file names with bash and am in need of a way to pull out a specific number from the string notated by a preceding character. Essentially, all of the files have a part of their name that looks like `D01` or `D02`. An example filename is `Build-asdasdasd.D01V02.dat`. I am trying to use sed, but to no avail thus far. Thanks!

Comment: Please improve your question by posting the relevant sections of your code, [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). In addition, please post the actual error message you received, and what steps you've taken so far to research or resolve your programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
name='Build-asdasdasd.D01V02.dat'

[[ "$name" =~ \.(D[[:digit:]]{2}[[:upper:]][[:digit:]]{2})\. ]] \
   && number="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" || number=''

echo  "'$number'"
```

The echo shows

```
'D01V02'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do everything in a single expression. You can build a pipeline, like so:

```
echo 'Build-asdasdasd.D01V02.dat' |
egrep -o '\.D([[:digit:]]{2}[^.]+)' |
sed 's/^.//'
```

This returns `D01V02` for me, but you may want to test your expression against a wider corpus to see if there are any edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another pure bash answer that assumes your filenames are always similar to the example. Regex is not required.

```
name='Build-asdasdasd.D01V02.dat'
number="${name%.*}"
number="${name##*.}"
echo "$number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. If you want the digits after the `D`, you can use

```
f="Build-asdasdasd.D01V02.dat"
num=$(grep -Po '(?<=D)\d\d' <<< "$f")
```

or

```
num=$(sed 's/^.*D\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\).*/\1/' <<< "$f")
```

Comment: You should note that -P is GNU-only.